# Outlook API: Getting free/busy status

Tags: windows, api, outlook

I searched around but couldn't find an answer. I'm not sure if this is possible, but seems it is.

What I basically want is to get my free/busy status according to Outlook in to a C++ program. For example, I want to check if I have an appointment and then print out "Free" or "Busy". Of course it will awesome if I can also get an description of the appointment.

Is there an easier way of doing this? 
Any tutorial or example link owuld be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms870482%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) should help . Let me know.

I am providing the contents of the link below :-

Checking Free/Busy Status

**Exchange Server 2003 - Checking Free/Busy Status**

```
Before you send a meeting request, you can check an attendee's calendar to see when the attendee is available. The IAddressee.GetFreeBusy method returns a string of numbers that indicate the attendee's availability for a requested period of time.
Each number in the free/busy string represents an interval of time (every ½ hour in this example). Free time returns 0, Tentative returns 1, Busy returns 2, and Out of Office (OOF) returns 3. If appointments overlap, the highest number is returned. If no free/busy data is available for the interval, the value 4 is returned.
The following figure shows part of an attendee's calendar and the corresponding free/busy string.
The free/busy string for a part of an attendee's calendar
To get an attendee's free/busy status for a specific time, you can create an Addressee object and execute the IAddressee.GetFreeBusy method. You can also get the free/busy status for longer intervals and parse the string to find times the attendee is free.
Note  You must first call the IAddressee.CheckName method and resolve the addressee before you can use the IAddressee.GetFreeBusy method.
Note  An automated process in Microsoft® Exchange Server 2003 periodically updates the free/busy status of users. Microsoft Outlook® updates the free/busy status of Outlook users. Collaboration Data Objects (CDO) synchronizes the Outlook free/busy cache with free/busy information from CDO clients. The free/busy status is not updated immediately when a meeting is added to a user's calendar. By default, three months' worth of free/busy status is maintained in a system folder in the Exchange store.
This topic contains Microsoft Visual Basic®, Microsoft Visual C++®, Microsoft C#, and Visual Basic .NET code examples.
Visual Basic
The following example returns the free/busy status of the specified user:
' Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library
' Reference to Microsoft CDO for Exchange 2000 Library

' Note: It is recommended that all input parameters be validated when they are
' first obtained from the user or user interface.
Function GetFreeBusyString(strUserUPN As String, dtStartDate As Date, dtEndDate As Date, Interval As Integer) As String

    Dim iAddr    As New CDO.Addressee
    Dim freebusy As String
    Dim Info     As New ADSystemInfo

    iAddr.EmailAddress = strUserUPN
    If Not iAddr.CheckName("LDAP://" & Info.DomainDNSName) Then
        ' handle error
    End If

    'Get the free/busy status in Interval minute intervals from dtStartDate to dtEndDate
    freebusy = iAddr.GetFreeBusy(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, Interval)
    GetFreeBusyString = freebusy

End Function


C++
The following example returns the free/busy status of the specified user:
/*
 Assume that the following paths are in your
 INCLUDE path.
 %CommonProgramFiles%\system\ado
 %CommonProgramFiles%\microsoft shared\cdo
*/

#import <msado15.dll> no_namespace
#import <cdoex.dll> no_namespace
#include <iostream.h>

// Note: It is recommended that all input parameters be validated when they are
// first obtained from the user or user interface.
bstr_t getFreeBusyString( const bstr_t& userUPN, const bstr_t& domainDNSName, DATE startDate, DATE endDate, long Interval) {

   IAddresseePtr iAddr(__uuidof(Addressee));

   iAddr->EmailAddress = userUPN;
   if(iAddr->CheckName(bstr_t("LDAP://") + domainDNSName, bstr_t(), bstr_t()) == VARIANT_FALSE) {
      cerr << "Error looking up name!" << endl;
      _com_issue_error(E_FAIL);
   }

    //Get the free/busy status in Interval minute intervals from startDate to endDate
   return iAddr->GetFreeBusy(startDate, endDate, Interval, bstr_t(), bstr_t(), bstr_t(), bstr_t());

}

C#
The following example returns the free/busy status of the specified user:
// Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library
// Reference to Microsoft CDO for Exchange 2000 Library
// Reference to Active DS Type Library

// Note: It is recommended that all input parameters be validated when they are
// first obtained from the user or user interface.
static string GetFreeBusyString(string strUserUPN, DateTime dtStartDate,
                                DateTime dtEndDate, int Interval)
{
   try
   {
      // Variables.
      CDO.Addressee iAddr = new CDO.Addressee();
      string freebusy;
      ActiveDs.ADSystemInfo Info = new ActiveDs.ADSystemInfo();

      iAddr.EmailAddress = strUserUPN;
      if  (!(iAddr.CheckName("LDAP://" + Info.DomainDNSName, "", "")))
         throw new System.Exception("Error occured!");

      // Get the free/busy status in Interval minute
      // intervals from dtStartDate to dtEndDate.
      freebusy = iAddr.GetFreeBusy(dtStartDate, dtEndDate,
                                   Interval, "", "", "", "");

      return freebusy;
   }
   catch (Exception err)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
      return "";
   }
}
Visual Basic .NET
The following example returns the free/busy status of the specified user:
' Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library
' Reference to Microsoft CDO for Exchange 2000 Library
' Reference to Active DS Type Library

' Note: It is recommended that all input parameters be validated when they are
' first obtained from the user or user interface.
Function GetFreeBusyString(ByVal strUserUPN As String, ByVal dtStartDate As Date, _
                           ByVal dtEndDate As Date, ByVal Interval As Integer) As String

   Try
      ' Variables.
      Dim iAddr As New CDO.Addressee()
      Dim freebusy As String
      Dim Info As New ActiveDs.ADSystemInfo()

      iAddr.EmailAddress = strUserUPN
      If Not iAddr.CheckName("LDAP://" & Info.DomainDNSName) Then
         Throw New System.Exception("Error occured!")
      End If

     ' Get the free/busy status in Interval minute intervals
     ' from dtStartDate to dtEndDate.
     freebusy = iAddr.GetFreeBusy(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, Interval)
     GetFreeBusyString = freebusy

   Catch err As Exception
      Console.WriteLine(err.ToString())
      GetFreeBusyString = ""
   End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Sujay. I think thats what I was looking for although a little too complicated :) I will go through that.

Comment: @madu - Please accept the answer as it shall help users, who are looking for answers for the same question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @shuttle87 I have added the text.